# Adding numbers within a function

Tags: javascript, html

So what i'm trying to do is to call a function using onclick and when that function activates the total will add 5 on to itself e.g. 0+ 5 = 10, then when called again it will remain at 5 and do 5 + 5 = 10, 10 + 5 = 15 etc.

```js
 var total = 0;
 function addFive(){
  var a = 0;
  var b = 5;
  var c = a + b;
  alert(c)
  var total = total + c;
  alert(total)
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="£5" onClick="addFive()" id="butFive">
```

Comment: *e.g. 0+ 5 = 10* o_O

Comment: Don't redeclare new total variable using `var`

Comment: Why not just doing total += 5 inside your function?

Comment: Instead of this: `var total = total + c;` try `total = total + c;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> var total = total + c;
> ```

Using `var` declares a new variable (with the same name) in the current scope. It masks the `total` in the wider name.

Don't use `var` here.

```js
var total = 0;

function addFive() {
  var a = 0;
  var b = 5;
  var c = a + b;
  total = total + c;
  console.log(total)
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="£5" onClick="addFive()" id="butFive">
```

Comment: Not sure if its right to answer this question. Not even sure if this falls under typo mistake.

Comment: Sadly i need it to continue from the previous value. So the function would get it to 5, i'd then store it then when the function is called again it's 5 + 5.
Sorry if i explained it weird.

Comment: @MatthewWallace — That's what this does!

Comment: Sorry mate, i'm an idiot i wasn't looking at the console.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in javascript has function scope. It means, that defining variable inside function hides global definition. In your case, first declared `total` variable has global scope and then you hide it inside your function.
In fact, you are assigning value to local, each time created variable.

To solve your problem, try:

```
total = total + c;
```